# Is "sweating" a gerund or adjective -ing in this context "we would certainly be sweating if we went on a round-trip journey of 32 KM by bicycle."

Tags: tense, gerunds

Is `sweating` a `gerund` or `adjective + -ing` in this context:

> we would certainly be sweating if we went on a round-trip journey of
>   32 KM by bicycle.

I think `sweating` is not gerund as subject,gerund as complement nor gerund as object.

And according this artice https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/adjectives-ending-ed-and-ing:

> Adjectives that end ‘-ing’ describe the thing that causes the emotion
>   – a boring lesson makes you feel bored.

As far as i know `sweating` is not a emotion too. I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

No, *sweating* here is a **present participle**, used with auxiliary *be* to form the **progressive aspect**.  It is neither a gerund nor an adjective.

The verb *sweat* here is used in its most basic meaning, "to produce liquid on the surface of your skin when you are hot, nervous, or sick" ([Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sweat_9)).  In this case, the speaker would be sweating due to physical exertion.

This sentence doesn't talk about emotion.

Comment: Just like "She went shopping" ?

Comment: Ahhh I found it, It's future progresive tense, isn't it @snailboat ?